# Interpreting partial dependence plots (marginal effects) using plotmo

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, boosting

I'm computing partial dependence plots to visualize the relationship between predictors (including interactions) and outcome. I study patients with brain tumours and mortality is very high (90%). I use random forest (randomForest package) to perform binary classification (dead yes/no). Moreover, I use the plotmo package, which appears to be outstanding for visualizing such relationships, to visualize the variable relationships. Below is the output from plotmo, where the interaction between age and metastasis is visualized:

[image]

My questions are actually noted on the image. Using the built-in partial dependence plots in the randomForest package does not help to clarify these things). Reading the package tutorials on CRAN did not help as well.

Please refer to the image above to see what is unclear regarding this.

I'm deeply grateful for any thoughts you guys may offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About the vertical axis:**

The [plotmo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotmo/index.html)
function calls `predict` internally to generate the graph.  So the vertical
axis will be plotted in whatever units `predict` returns for your model.

In your example for a `randomForest` model, the default prediction type is
`"response"` (see the help page for
`predict.randomForest`).  Change this by passing `type="prob"`
to plotmo, which plotmo will pass on internally to `predict.randomForest`.

For example (see the two graphs on the left):

```
library(rpart.plot); data(ptitanic)  # for ptitanic data
dat <- ptitanic[,c("survived", "sex", "pclass")] # classic example
library(randomForest)
mod <- randomForest(survived~., data=dat)
plotmo(mod) # default predict type is "response"
plotmo(mod, type="prob")
```

[image: plot]

**About the horizontal axes:**

Since the `persp` function accepts only numeric
(not factor) arguments , plotmo converts factor variables to numeric
before invoking `persp` internally.  Thus a factor of say `"blue",
"green", "red"` will be plotted as `1,2,3` in plotmo's `persp`plot
(`1,2,3` are the integers used internally by R to represent the
factor).

**Axis labels:**

Get more information on the axes by invoking `persp`
with `ticktype="detailed"`.  To do this, pass
`persp.ticktype="detailed"` to plotmo (any plotmo argument prefixed
by `persp.` gets passed on internally to the `persp` function, this is described near the bottom of
the plotmo help page).

For example (see the two graphs on the right):

```
plotmo(mod, type="prob", persp.ticktype="detailed")
plotmo(mod, type="prob", persp.ticktype="detailed", persp.nticks=3)
```

Bear in mind that plotmo does automatic determination of the
response axis range. See the `ylim` argument of plotmo and Section 5.4 of the
[vignette for the plotmo package](http://www.milbo.org/doc/plotmo-notes.pdf).
This automatic determination can sometimes cause surprising results.

To plot partial dependence graphs, don't forget that we need to pass `type="partdep"`
to plotmo.  See Chapters 1 and 9 of the
[plotmo vignette](http://www.milbo.org/doc/plotmo-notes.pdf).

Comment: Great clarification Stephen, and thanks for creating a beautiful R package.